# using vuex to generate chartjs chart problem

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuex

I am a beginner in Vue and I want to create a project that uses Chart.js. I am using Vuex and am having a trouble to generate the data into the component.

```
<script>
    import{Line} from 'vue-chartjs';
    import {mapGetters,mapActions} from 'vuex';
    export default {
        extends:Line,
        data: () => ({
            chartdata: {
                labels: ['January', 'February'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Data One',
                        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                        data: this.currentDeath
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false
            }
        }),
        methods:{
            ...mapActions(["fetchData"]),
        },
        computed:{
            ...mapGetters(["currentDeath"])
        },
        created(){
           this.fetchData()
        },
        mounted(){
            const dates = this.
            this.renderChart(this.chartData,this.options)
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

It says on localhost that "currentDeath is undefined". However if I were to print it on screen it is populated with an array of data. Anyone knows how I can access its data?